# Update in sorted order

Tags: sql, postgresql, csv, sql-update

Do you know of a way to run an update, where the update will automatically insert a new numerical value into a comma separated string in numerical order?

```
SELECT ids FROM some.place;

ids
-------------------------
 {13,24,29,35,42,61,82}
```

Comment: The best thing to do is *not store comma separated lists in the first place*: http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/55871/7788

Comment: replaced the tag for the Postgres commandline client `psql` with `postgresql`

Answer (score 1):

In this case, because your "comma separated string" is a valid PostgreSQL array literal, you can cast to `integer[]` and use the `intarray` extension's `sort()` method.

```
CREATE EXTENSION intarray;

UPDATE some_place
SET ids = sort( ids::integer[] || new_value )::text
WHERE ...
```

In general, storing comma separated lists in fields is really bad design. Use an array if you must, but don't just store it as text.

e.g.

```
regress=> select sort( '{13,24,29,35,42,61,82}'::integer[] || 18 )::text;
           sort            
---------------------------
 {13,18,24,29,35,42,61,82}
(1 row)
```

Comment: Looks like intarray isn't an option.

# CREATE EXTENSION intarray;
ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/pgsql-9.3/share/extension/intarray.control": No such file or directory

Comment: @user3486527 You just need to install the contrib package